# Writing a CSV with multiple variables

Tags: python, csv

I currently have two lists:

```
lat = [34.78, 34.82, 34.86, 34.92]
lon = [-86.02, -86.06, -86.10, -86.14]
```

I am trying to write a csv file that outputs them as lat/lon:

```
34.78, -86.02
34.82, -86.06
34.86, -86.10
34.92, -86.14
```

I tried using:

```
with open('lat_lon', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(lat)
    writer.writerow(lon)
```

But this gives me the lat values all in one row and the lon values in a separate row.  Any ideas on how to correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to [*zip*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and use *writerows* instead of writerow:

```
with open('lat_lon', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(zip(lat, lon))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, do this:

```
with open('lat_lon', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for la, lo in zip(lat, lon):
        writer.writerow([la, lo])
```

Or more concise (as pointed out above):

```
with open('lat_lon', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(zip(lat, lon))
```

Comment: You snatched my answer while I was typing it!

Comment: Sorry, this happens! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
lat = [34.78, 34.82, 34.86, 34.92]
lon = [-86.02, -86.06, -86.10, -86.14]

output = pd.DataFrame(lat, columns=['lat'])
output['lon'] = lon
output.to_csv('lat_lon', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point is zip(lat, lon). You can make the above answers more compact like this.

```
import csv
with open('lat_lon', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(zip(lat, lon))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this readymade example:

```
import csv
fileName = './fileName.csv' # modify both file name and path if required
def WriteToCSV(fileName, col_1, col_2, col_3):
    row = [col_1, col_2, col_3]
    with open(fileName, 'a', newline='') as f:  # create and/ or opening the csv file in append mode
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(row)


col_1 = 'col_1'
col_2 = 'col_2'
col_3 = 'col_3'
WriteToCSV(fileName, col_1, col_2, col_3) # calling the function
```

Good luck.