# Writing a CSV with multiple variables with fieldnames python

Tags: python, csv, pycharm, export-to-csv, field-names

Im very new to python so please be kind... I need to write a csv file with multiple variables and a fieldname. I found a different post:
[Writing a CSV with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252515/writing-a-csv-with-multiple-variables)

But i have 0 clue how to add a fieldname. I know that it has to be something like:

```
with open('lat_lon', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['lat','lon']
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader
    writer.writerows(zip(lat, long)
```

if you can help me that would be great!

btw I'm using python 3.10.4 and pycharm community edition 2021.3.3 on mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names in a csv file are no more than the first row of that file. So at the beginning you can simply write a row with the desired field names in your csv file:

```
import csv

with open('lat_lon.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['lat', 'lon'])
    # ...
```